Shortcut to lock/unloack all Transform parameter
When an object is selected, We can see the transform parameter on the right side panel where there are locks icon :

The question : How to turn on/off these locks using shortcut so I can lock all the transforms (location,rot,scale) at a time using a single shortcut ? or at least a shortcut for each these location, rotation and scale parameter.

You can do this easily just by using the mouse. Click and hold the LMB over the top icon to set/unset it and drag the mouse down over the other icons.


Here's a short and easy python script I came up with. It might be a bit tedious to go back and forth with the text editor to run this script, but it works. Just change lock=True to lock all of them and then lock=False to unlock all of them.
import bpy

def lock_all_transforms(obj, lock=True):
    for i in range(3):
        obj.lock_location[i] = lock
        obj.lock_rotation[i] = lock
        obj.lock_scale[i] = lock

#To lock all transforms
lock_all_transforms(bpy.context.object, lock=True)

